# Creating roles on mySQL with different types of users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a web application and I'm using MySQL. I need to create 3 types of users:
Administrator, Operator and Viewer. Each type of of user has some privileges, for example:

- Adm = Can do almost everything
- Operator = Can insert, select only on 3-4 tables of the database
- Viewer= can only select tables

How would you suggest me to do this on mySQL?
Should I create a table users with the attributes : name, pass, type
or should I create a table for every type such:

1. table "adm" with attributes = name, pass
2. table "op" with attributes = name, pass

Also should I create 3 different roles and then grant them to the users?

Comment: I would suggest you create 3 types of user in MySQL, and create a php configuration file for each. Then, depending on who logs in, you assign them the corresponding configuration file.

Comment: What about in sql? Should I create one table called "users" for all the 3 types of them? How can I give them different privileges?

Comment: This question to first seight seams to broad to be answerd or primarily opinion based, which is considerd to be offtopic here..  Not to forget also very unclear

Comment: For this kind of thing, you can use MySQL's built-in user tables.